# Abbreviation for "requirements"

Tags: grammaticality, word-usage, abbreviations

**What is the correct abbreviation for the word "requirements"?**

Specifically, I am looking for the *plural form* of the abbreviation.

I have seen various usages including:

- req's
- reqs.
- REQS
- REQs
- rqmts.

Are any of the above considered the correct form?

I am inclined to believe that *req's* is incorrect because it appears to be a contraction or in the possessive form.

*REQS* and *REQs* appear to be acronyms, which implies that each letter stands for some unique word.

So, it seems that *reqs.* and *rqmts.* are likely candidates to be the correct form, but I cannot find any definitive sources.

FWIW: As I type this question, my browser is marking only *rqmts.* with a spell check red underline. Indicating that perhaps all of the other options may be acceptable.

Comment: Well, one has to ask *correct according to who(m)?* You're free to abbreviate it anyway you want. There could be several "acceptable" abbreviations. Why do you need to abbreviate the word?

Comment: You should not trust your browser as it can't recognize whether those abbreviations are for request or requirements (for example). What @Clare said, I think it will depend on your readers.

Comment: a) By *correct* I suppose I mean *widely used* ***and*** *least likely to be misinterpreted*. Or, if there is a *definitive* source that you can reference, such as a dictionary or standards manual, that would give me additional confidence in usage. b) I am using the word in a subsection title of a document where I do not want the title to wrap to a new line. This word is the best choice for abbreviation after reducing the length of the title already.

Comment: Care to share the subtitle? I'm not convinced *rqmts* is less ambiguous than *reqmts* (which I might use), but when one abbreviates, one is cutting out text! Note *reqt* is given for both *requirement* and *request* and   could be misinterpreted if the context weren't clear.

Comment: And note others may use different abbreviations. US Army and others, perhaps.

Comment: I've always used *reqt* and *reqts*. But I probably wouldn't use an abbreviation in any important communication. I use it when taking notes for myself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*A Dictionary of Abbreviations*, Burt Vance (Oxford University Press) lists the following as  abbreviations for 'requirement':

> reqmt
>   reqt
>   rqmt

and for requirements

> rqmts

I guess  you  could add an *s* and get  *reqts* and *reqmts*. So far I haven't seen a period (.) used after any abbreviation in this resource.

Note *reqt* is also given for *request*, which I think shows even with abbreviations, ambiguity is possible.

For *reqs* it lists *requires*.

A link  for *rqmts* is [this](http://www.oxfordreference.com/view/10.1093/acref/9780199698295.001.0001/acref-9780199698295-e-87068?rskey=DxHISe&result=89322) but I don't know if it's visible because I'm accessing it through my library.

Comment: Can you provide a link to an online resource, if available? Also, is it convention to use it with or without a period?

Comment: [Link is here](http://www.oxfordreference.com/view/10.1093/acref/9780199698295.001.0001/acref-9780199698295?btog=chap&hide=true&jumpTo=req&page=1746&pageSize=50&skipEditions=true&sort=titlesort&source=%2F10.1093%2Facref%2F9780199698295.001.0001%2Facref-9780199698295). It also shows `REQ` as request, eliminating other options posted.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the link! It actually lists [*rqmts*](http://www.oxfordreference.com/view/10.1093/acref/9780199698295.001.0001/acref-9780199698295-e-87068?rskey=DxHISe&result=89322) as the abbreviation for the plural form of *requirements*.

Comment: @Clare, yes, your link works. Thanks for updating the answer with the options and links. Accepted!

Comment: Thanks for that particular link @Hank. Is that a public link? (I link to the resource through my library.)

Comment: @Clare Mine is public yes. Although, your link worked fine for me.

Comment: @Hank I've  changed the link to yours,   just in case. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score -2):

A solid answer to the question is here: http://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/abbreviations/#Q5

> *Can I use abbreviations in the title of a paper?*
>
> *Avoid using abbreviations in the title of a paper. Writing out the full term in the title will ensure potential readers know exactly what
> you mean, and if your article is formally published, it will ensure it
> is accurately indexed.*

This guideline overrides formatting concerns like not wanting to put part of a subtitle on another line.

Comment: doesn't answer the question

Comment: The original author for this question explained in a later comment: "I am using the word in a subsection title of a document where I do not want the title to wrap to a new line. This word is the best choice for abbreviation after reducing the length of the title already." 
My answer addresses his underlying reasons for wishing to abbreviate this word in the first place and it is therefor a valid response to the question. (One of my hard-learned life lessons applies here: always remember to consider questioning the question itself.)